# Rendering object with an entire view in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Il laravel when you are told to render some data you are explained that you should send data from controller to view

```
Route::get('/', function()
   $posts = MyRep::giveMeAllPosts();
   return View::make('listing', $posts);
});
```

with a view

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <li>{{ $post->title }} - {{ $post->published_at }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Is there any way you could have objects (for example Models, ModelViews or other type) that would render entire view?

something like that:

```
<!-- View stored in resources/views/greeting.php -->
 @foreach($posts as $post)
        {{ $post->presenter('listing')->render()}}
    @endforeach
```

where the view for each item is defined in other view.

```
<!-- View stored in resources/views/listing.php -->
<li>{{ $post->title }} - {{ $post->published_at }}</li>
```

In this way: the view for the listing will be decoupled from item view

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use include?

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    @include('listing')
@endforeach
```

And it will use your view:

```
<!-- View stored in resources/views/listing.php -->
<li>{{ $post->title }} - {{ $post->published_at }}</li>
```

But if you still need to render something from inside your models or repositories, you can there do:

```
{{ $post->render('listing') }}
```

In your model you would do:

```
public function render($what)
{
    $data = $this->produceListinData($what);

    return View::render($data->viewName, compact('data'));
}
```

And, of course, better would be to use a view presenter, as you did, but you'll probably will have to install a package to help you with that, or create your own. This is the one I use: https://github.com/laracasts/Presenter.

EDIT:

Anyway, I 100% agree with your comment about accessing a view from the model. A nice design solution in this case is to create a rendering service and a repository, to use your rendering service via your repository and your model would never have to know of the existence of views.

Comment: Your example will work but it will not decouple the two viwes. Let's say my "post" is a car, and depending of its brand name it has diferent view: ford.blade.php, mercedes.blade.tpl. That "logic" of choosing which view I would include  has to be outside of the view.

Comment: Got it. Edited to provider a way to do it inside your models, or repositories, or services...

Comment: Accesing the view from the model sounds a little bit weird. Doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Edited to explain what I think about this.